# How can I change the display name of an API console Service user?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using an API Console type Service user to create and share files with users. The name of the Service user appears in the UI as a long, unintelligible string. How can I change it please?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to edit the Google profile of a service account, therefore you can't modify the display name.

Comment: So if I want to have a readable user name, would I have to use a normal gmail address as a service account? In that case, would I have to keep the access token fresh?

Comment: has this changed at all? Any way to change the display name used to send emails etc...? This looks pretty bad...